# On windows system,I get this error-The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configurationn

Tags: windows, phpmyadmin, wamp

I get this error when I go to localhost/phpmyadmin (I am using WAMP).
I have windows...so the sudo -apt commands solution won't work.Also the line-

extension=php_mbstring.dll     is commented out.Any other reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay..so backstage I had this warning on my localhost at the bottom:

> *** ERROR *** The PHP configuration loaded file is: c:/wamp/bin/apache /apache2.4.17/php.ini - should be: C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.17 /bin/php.ini or c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.15/phpforapache.ini

I did this-
1.open cmd.Change the dir to bin of your apache dir.

> cd C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin

2. type

   > mklink php.ini C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.15\phpForApache.ini
3. the cmd read...

   > symbolic link created for php.ini <<===>> C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.15 \phpForApache.ini
4. exit the cmd and restart your wamp.

Comment: All you need to do is click `refresh` to rebuild all the `SYMLINKS` i.e. `right click wampmanager->refresh`

Comment: Thanks.Yes,we needed to rebuild the symlinks.